# How to block images from a specific domain?

Tags: firefox, google-chrome, images, blocking

I want to block images from all Google search services, except Google Images and captchas.

I've tried both `tools>options>content>exceptions` on Firefox and `options>content settings>images>manage exceptions` on Google Chrome with no luck. They work for other sites but not google.com.

Comment: Nowadays it's being done with uBlock Origin or similar. FF removed the feature.

Answer (score 7):

To block images originating from a specific domain, right click on the image & select View Image Info in the Firefox context menu. In the Page Info dialog box that opens, check the *Block images from {domain}*. Older versions of Firefox had the *Block images from {domain}* directly in the context menu.

[image: Firefox Page Info - Media]

Images can also be shown without using an image tag or by declaring a background image in CSS. [You can embed the image data directly into the document with data URIs.](http://css-tricks.com/data-uris/) In such cases, it may not be possible to block those "images".

Comment: +1. A method for times when right-clicking an image doesn't show `View Image Info` could be right-clicking on the background or on a text(but not a link) and choose `View Page Info`, then navigating to the `Media` tab. Be sure to check the address of your intended picture, because not all the pictures of a page are from the same origin. I don't know if it addresses the problem mentioned above about embedded images.

Comment: This tick box doesn't exist as of version 74.0 :(