# How to block all cross-site image requests originating for a specific website in Firefox?

Tags: firefox, blocking

I'm using Firefox 38 and OS can either be Windows 7, Ubuntu 14.04, or Slackware 14.1.

I want to know a way to block all cross-site image requests originating for a specific website. E.g. Consider Superuser.com where images from Gravatar.com, Imgur.com, and other user posted images from Dropbox, Google photos appears. To me, requests to  all of the said  websites account as cross-site image requests for SuperUser.com.

In a nutshell, if I visit ABC.com then I would like to know a way to block all images (all types, including animated and video previews) that are not from ABC.com but from other sources.

#### Things I tried so far:

1. Third party images can be stopped loading by changing the value of `permissions.default.image` to `3` in [`about:config`](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Permissions.default.image). However, this setting applies globally which is unproductive for me.
2. Per-site permissions via **Page Info -> Permission -> Load Images -> Block** isn't working for me somehow.

   I found that `permissions.sqlite` in current Firefox profile has  image related permissions. I changed it to `3` but to no avail.
3. I tried  [Image Block](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/image-block/) and [QuickJava](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/quickjava/) but they do global image blocking, and I would have to interfere in my browsing by tapping their icon on toolbar to enable/disable them.
4. [RequestPolicy](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/requestpolicy/) does the job well but the addon always runs in Whitelist mode while I require Blacklist mode in it.
5. I couldn't come up with a technique to use [Adblock Plus](https://addons.mozilla.org/En-us/firefox/addon/adblock-plus/) for the goal since it also works with Whitelist mode. ([Related](https://superuser.com/a/634635/423702))

**Note** that I cannot afford to go for a image hunt by using the solution [here](https://superuser.com/a/492783/423702) since the specific website could be any amongst the websites I visit, and cross-websites can be too much to kill for using that solution.

So, how do I achieve my goal?

**Edit**: Can per link based cross-site image blocking be achieved compared to per domain based? [This answer](https://superuser.com/a/933506/423702) achieves the latter. E.g. I wouldn't want to see any image on this [page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1939/kbd-elements-are-way-intrusive/23571#23571) of Meta.SE but I have no issues with loading third-party images on other pages (like [this page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/257889/pending-vlq-flag-in-flag-history-not-reflected-on-actual-questions-page)) of Meta.SE.

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve by doing that?

Comment: @DanielBeck I don't want images from other websites to be visible when I load some ABC.com. Not globally but for ABC.com. // I reduced the scope for answering, see my edit please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [imglikeopera](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/imglikeopera/) plugin has an option:

- load images for the originating Web site only;

that you can set for a given website only (called a filter) using the preferences/settings. You can export/import the filters for easier editing. An example file contents to block this page:

```
[ImgLikeOpera]
http://http://superuser.com/questions/933496/ 4
```

Comment: In the reviews someone [says](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/imglikeopera/reviews/710898/) to work on firefox 37 do this "Go to about:config and change browser.cache.use_new_backend_temp to false"

Comment: +1 Thank you very much since the addon is very helpful. Could you please add an example of the filter? Can this filter achieve per link based cross-site image blocking compared to domain based which it currently does? E.g. Can the filter achieve: blocking all non-[SU] images (like Imgur, gravatar) on current page but does not block all images on other pages of [SU]?

Comment: I think it can do what you want. If the default is to load all images, you can provide a filter rule which is just the url of the page you want to block, and select dont load images.

Comment: Thanks a lot since it does the job precisely. I wish it could have auto reload functionality but that's a request reserved for developer only. :) As for the favor to ask, would you please post or link your answer to [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/259565/286110) and [this](http://superuser.com/questions/895850/blocking-images-flash-gifs-on-specific-tab-in-firefox) question? That would be very kind of you since I don't want to get reputation solely based on your efforts here.

Comment: @Firelord, done. thanks. (I wouldnt have minded if you had answered those questions).